# using string splits as arguments to another method

Tags: java

I have a file reader that reads the text 
(a,b) (b,c) (c,d) (f,g) (c,g) (c,t) (h,i) (j,y)
and displays

```
a,b

b,c ....
```

is there a way to use these indexes as arguments for a method I call right after i'm done reading it? so far I seem to only effect the string split while i'm inside my `While` loop, is there a way to take value a and use it for  method like
add.edge("argument0","argument1") where 0 is a, and 1 is b?

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

class reader{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        File file = new File("test.txt");     
        BufferedReader fi = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String num;
        int count = 0;

        while ((num = fi.readLine()) !=null) {
            String [] add = num.split(" ");      
            for(int i=0; i<add.length;i++){
                String [] add2 =add[i].split("[)(]+");
                    for (String val: add2){
                        System.out.println(val);    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to call add.edge(add2[0], add[1])? If not, could you give a more concrete example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Risto Pärnapuu  that's exactly what i'm trying to do, but it only knows add[] when its in the loop, how can I integrate this into my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are trying to achieve some thing like following :D
i changed your code a little bit i used sub string instead of regular expression

```
import java.io.*;

class reader{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        File file = new File("test.txt");     
        BufferedReader fi = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String num;
        int count = 0;

        while ((num = fi.readLine()) !=null) {
            String [] add = num.split(" ");      
            for(int i=0; i<add.length;i++){
               String pair = add[i].substring(1, 4);
                someFunction(pair.split(","));
                }
            }
        }

public static void someFunction(String[] args)
  {
    if(args.length > 0)
      System.out.println(args[0] + " and " + args[1]);
  }

    }
```

Comment: this is great, also i'm doing a topological sort with this info, my method is     public void addEdge(int u,int v)
    {
        adj[u].add(v);
    }    how can I assign these two types? (I know string can't convert to int but its what I got working in the rest of my code)

Comment: you can start a new question . . .with your workaround on this and   .yes if above code is the solution then mark it as solution as it will help others

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the result of the split function outside the while loop you need to save the results to a variable that is defined before the while loop. This is because currently the scope of the add2 variable in inside the for loop and thus you will only be able to use it inside the for loop. If you want to save pairs of Strings then I suggest creating a helper class Pair:

```
class Pair {

  private String el1;
  private String el2;

  public Pair(String el1, String el2) {
    this.el1 = el1;
    this.el2 = el2;
  }

  // getters
}
```

and make a list of pairs defined before the while loop:

```
List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
```

and in your for loop, add new pairs to the list:

```
pairs.add(new Pair(add2[0], add[1])));
```

Then you can access the list elements outside the while loop like so:

```
for (Pair pair : pairs) {
  add.edge(pair.getEl1(), pair.getEl2());
}
```